# How to test a non-angular form submission in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a component with a paypal button in the HTML, like this:

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
  <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="key-goes-here" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Donate!</button>
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

There is nothing in the component TS file. It has no logic.

I'd like to add a test to make sure the form submission always happens when the button is clicked, so I figured I'd `spyOn` the native `submit` function of the form element, click the button, and then just check that `form.submit` was called.

But I get the error:

> Expected spy submit to have been called.

Here is my test file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { DonateButtonComponent } from './donate-button.component';

describe('DonateButtonComponent', () => {
  let component: DonateButtonComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DonateButtonComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DonateButtonComponent],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DonateButtonComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should redirect to Paypal when the button is clicked', () => {
    const btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn'));
    const form: HTMLFormElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form')).nativeElement;

    spyOn(form, 'submit');
    btn.triggerEventHandler('click', {});

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(form.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: At this point, you are testing HTML and it has already been tested. I would skip out on this test. Also, why not do this the Angular way of writing a template or reactive form where the submit button is clicked, a method is called that does the `Http.Post` from a service? This way, you can test out different scenarios (error handling, success handling, etc.).

Comment: True, I was beginning to wonder if this even required a test since it really had no logic and nothing could break. I think I'll just skip it.   The reason for not using "angular forms" of any kind is that there's no need. This just submits a form to Paypal and the page is redirected to a donation page.  That's the code snippet straight from PayPal.